# Selenium Web Scraping find_element_by_xpath error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some data (eg. Dealer Name, Address, Phone# & Email ID) from a page https://www.mahindrausa.com/map-hours-directions-tractors-utvs-farming-equipment--dealership--locate-a-dealer using python with selenium library, but I can't extract the text using 'find_element_by_xpath' command.

Whenever I run the below program it gives me blank text with an error, I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. Below is the error

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="locationsAR"]/div/ul/li[1]/a[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Can someone please help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

data={}
abvr=['AL','AR','AZ','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','IA','ID','IL','IN','KS','KY','LA','MA','MD','ME','MI','MN','MO','MS','MT','NC','ND','NH','NJ','NM','NV','NY','OH','OK','OR','PA','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VA','VT','WA','WI','WV','WY']
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Address 1','Address 2','Phone#','Email'])
path=r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.mahindrausa.com/map-hours-directions-tractors-utvs-farming-equipment--dealership--locate-a-dealer")
a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("locations-list")
for s in abvr:
    name="locations"+s
    for n in a:
        for k in n.find_elements_by_class_name("state-location"):
            count=1
            names= '//*[@id=\"'+name+'\"]/div/ul/li['+str(count)+']/h4'
            address1='//*[@id=\"'+name+'\"]/div/ul/li['+str(count)+']/span[1]/span[1]'
            address2='//*[@id=\"'+name+'\"]/div/ul/li['+str(count)+']/span[1]/span[2]'
            phone='//*[@id=\"'+name+'\"]/div/ul/li['+str(count)+']/span[2]/a'
            email='//*[@id=\"'+name+'\"]/div/ul/li['+str(count)+']/a[2]'
            data['Name']=k.find_element_by_xpath(names).text
            data['Address 1']=k.find_element_by_xpath(address1).text
            data['Address 2']=k.find_element_by_xpath(address2).text
            data['Phone#']=k.find_element_by_xpath(phone).text
            data['Email']=k.find_element_by_xpath(email).text
            df=df.append(data,ignore_index=True)
            count=+1
driver.quit()
print(df)
```

Comment: Unless you use [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to expand the cards, possibly you won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to collect the list of dealers, there could be a simpler solution. It appears that the complete list (498 dealers) is stored in one variable named `jCollection` which you can read with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.mahindrausa.com/map-hours-directions-tractors-utvs-farming-equipment--dealership--locate-a-dealer")
dealers = driver.execute_script("return jCollection;")
print(dealers)
```

**Output**

```
{'features': [{'geometry': {'coordinates': [36.16876, -84.07945],
    'type': 'Point'},
   'properties': {'address': '2401 N Charles G Seivers Blvd',
    'city': 'Clinton',
    'dealerCode': 'TOM08',
    'dealerName': " Tommy's Motorsports",
    ...
    }}]}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how did you find that the data is stored in one variable jCollection.  Good to know info for my future projects. Your help is much appreciated here.

Comment: When the page loads, it makes a call to get the dealers information: 
https://www.mahindrausa.com/js/locations.js?v=1.072
The first line of this page being : `var jCollection = ` here is how I found out

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath is pretty flaky. I tried finding an element with `//*[@id="locationsAR"]/div/ul/li[1]/a[2]` xpath and didn't find it, but I found something with `//*[@id="locationsAR"]/div/ul/li[1]/a`.

That's because you were trying to get the email for first Arizona location and it is blank:
there is no element with that xpath.